# How do I make an array with a key/value array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am optimizing some code. Some code I can change, some I can't.
I am querying the database and checking it against a json_decode() array that is the new data. I find the differences and add or delete from the database as needed.

UPDATE: This is my query:

> $sQuery = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM
>   my_table WHERE id=my_id;

UPDATE2:

OK, so my query goes into a custom query function that I cannot change and this is what comes out:

```
    mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 2
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 2
        [type] => 0
    )
```

I want to parse the result in such a way that is organized like this:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [column1] => value
           )
    [1] => Array
           (
               [column2] => value
           )
)
```

// end Update 2

I'm banging my head feeling stupid trying to parse the first array to match the organization of the second array. Help please?

Here is what I've tried:

```
while ($aRows = $aResults->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $sValue) {

        if ($iKey % 2 == 0)
            $aPreviousList[$iKey][] = $sValue;

        if ($iKey % 2 == 1)
            $aPreviousList[$iKey][] = $sValue;
    }
}
```

But it comes out like this:

```
Array
(
    [ixfChangeMethod] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 11
        )

    [sDetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => some details about 16
            [1] => some details about 11
        )

)
```

Am I going about this all wrong or is there another way I can parse both arrays that I can check the differences better?

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` should return a row where each member of the array is the name of the column... what does your query look like?

Comment: If you know you'll always have an even number of rows returned, you can just get a second row inside your loop; the first row will contain your key and the second your value.

Comment: I will have odd or even rows returned

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar i'll add my query above

Comment: How is that possible? Then you'll end up with a key without a value at the end.

Comment: As it's been hinted, `fetch_assoc()` will return an array like this: `array( array( 'column1' => value, 'column2' => value ), array( 'column1' => value, 'column2' => value ) )`

Comment: column1 = key, column2 = value?

Comment: yeah sorry, let me review what's in my question. I think I confused myself.. one sec.

Comment: Your query and example result array dose not match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed the code, is this better?

```
while ($aRow = $aResults->fetch_row()) {
    $aPreviousList[] = array($aRow[0] => $aRow[1]);
}
```

Comment: I double checked to make sure I changed all the variables to the correct variables in my code, but this returned an empty array. :-/

Comment: This just makes an array with an array containing only the 'details' column.

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [16] => some details
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [11] => asdfasdfasdasd
        )

)

`

Comment: Ok, i've rolled back my last change

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_assoc` returns an associative array.
`fetch_row` returns a numeric array.

So just use `fetch_row` instead of `fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
while ($aRows = $aResults->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $aPreviousList[]=array($aRows['column1']=>$aRows['column2']);
}

print_r($aPreviousList);
```